# Using VBA and CDO to send AOL message

Tags: vba, email, cdo.message, aol

I am trying to use VBA in Excel to send a message to an AOL address. I can get Gmail and Comcast to work, but not AOL.
Error: -2147220973 - The transport failed to connect to the server.
My code originated here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/send-emails-excel-vba/

Thank you for your assistance!

```
Option Explicit   
' Source from: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/send-emails-excel-vba/  
Sub Test_Email()
Dim sResult     As String    
    sResult = Send_Emails("somebody@aol.com", "MyPWD", "smtp.aol.com")        
    MsgBox "Finished: " & vbTab & sResult        
End Sub

Public Function Send_Emails(EmailAddress As String, PWD As String, SMTP As String) As String  
Dim NewMail     As CDO.Message
Dim mailConfig  As CDO.Configuration
Dim fields      As Variant
Dim msConfigURL As String

    On Error GoTo Err:
    Debug.Print "Send: " & EmailAddress & vbTab & PWD & vbTab & SMTP
    Set NewMail = New CDO.Message
    Set mailConfig = New CDO.Configuration
    mailConfig.Load -1          'load all default configurations
    Set fields = mailConfig.fields
    
    With NewMail
        .From = EmailAddress
        .To = "myname@comcast.net"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Send Email From an Excel Spreadsheet"
        .TextBody = "This is the body of your email. And here is some added data:" & "XXXX"
        .AddAttachment ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "openexcel.txt"        ' 'Optional file attachment; remove if not needed.
    End With

    msConfigURL = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration"

    With fields
        .item(msConfigURL & "/smtpusessl") = True                   'Enable SSL Authentication
        .item(msConfigURL & "/smtpauthenticate") = 1                'SMTP authentication Enabled
        .item(msConfigURL & "/smtpserver") = SMTP   'i.e. "smtp.aol.com"
        .item(msConfigURL & "/smtpserverport") = 465                'Set the SMTP port Details
        .item(msConfigURL & "/sendusing") = 2                       'Send using default setting
        .item(msConfigURL & "/sendusername") = EmailAddress   ' full xxx&aol.com      'Your gmail address
        .item(msConfigURL & "/sendpassword") = PWD                  'Your password or App Password
        .Update                 'Update the configuration fields
    End With
    NewMail.Configuration = mailConfig
    NewMail.send
   
    MsgBox "Your email has been sent", vbInformation

    Send_Emails = "Success!"
    
Exit_Err:
   'Release object memory
    Set NewMail = Nothing
    Set mailConfig = Nothing
    Exit Function
 Err:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case -2147220973 'Could be because of Internet Connection
        MsgBox "Check your internet connection." & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & 
 Err.Description
    Case -2147220975 'Incorrect credentials User ID or password
        MsgBox "Check your login credentials and try again." & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & 
Err.Description
    Case Else 'Report other errors
        MsgBox "Error encountered while sending email." & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & 
Err.Description
    End Select
    Resume Exit_Err
    Resume
End Function
```

Comment: I'll just say what everyone else is thinking.... *time to stop using your AOL address*...

Comment: Not my address... an elderly, challenged friend :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Outlook object model instead of CDO (not supported any longer).

Microsoft Outlook 2010 and later versions include many architectural changes to the client-side MAPI subsystem. Of particular concern are scenarios in which Outlook is configured to use multiple Exchange accounts. Also, CDO 1.2.1 is a 32-bit client library and will not operate with 64-bit versions of Outlook. Given all these factors, CDO 1.2.1 is not supported for use with Outlook 2010 or later versions, and MS does not recommend its use with Outlook 2010 and later versions.

Programs that use CDO should be redesigned to use other Application Programming Interfaces (APIs) instead of CDO. Starting with Outlook 2007, the Outlook object model was greatly expanded to provide functionality that was previously available only by using CDO 1.2.1. The Outlook 2010 and later versions object model includes some new features to expand on this more. For example, the Outlook object model has new functionality to operate correctly with multiple Exchange accounts. The Outlook object model also works for both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Outlook. Developers should use the Outlook 2010 and later object model instead of CDO 1.2.1. Also, developers can still use Extended MAPI (which requires unmanaged C++) in some scenarios where CDO was required. However, if it is possible, we generally recommend that the Outlook object model is used instead of Extended MAPI.

See [Collaboration Data Objects (CDO) 1.2.1 is not supported with Outlook 2010 and later versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/development/collaboration-data-objects-1-2-1-not-supported-in-outlook-2010-and-later) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Eugene. I now have created a module that sends messages using Outlook.  I sure hope the elderly person that I'm trying to help has Outlook installed on her PC!
Since I'm trying to get files sent to me from her PC, it is not important to send an email to her AOL address.
I appreciate your taking the time to respond!